Blazor server app - why IsAuthenticated property switches from True to False in Redirect call?
In my Blazor server web app I am doing authentication with Cognito. The problem I have is that the authentication state “IsAuthenticated” is True after the call to “SignInAsync”, but reverts back to False in the call to context.Response.Redirect("/"). No logout calls are done in the process.
I will appreciate a helping hand in figuring out what can be the problem. Code snippets are below.
Login callback:
app.MapGet("/signin", async (HttpContext context)
{
…
var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("id_token", idToken), email, username, userid };
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
await context.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
await Task.Delay(100);
// **at this point IsAuthenticated property  is set to “true”**
var updatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
var authStateProvider = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationStateProvider>() as AuthStateProvider;

authStateProvider?.NotifyUserAuthentication(claimsPrincipal);
context.Response.Redirect("/");  **// at this point, in my custom Auth State Provider, “IsAuthenticated” value is false.**
}
 
public class AuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private ClaimsPrincipal _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var authstate = new AuthenticationState(_currentUser);
        return Task.FromResult(authstate);
    }

    public void NotifyUserAuthentication(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        _currentUser = user;
        var authstate = GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
    }

    public void NotifyUserLogout()
    {
        _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser)));
    }
}

